# Firefox compatibility issues with aligning

Tags: css, firefox, html, alignment

how can i align the navigation text back on to the bar

This is what it should look like (and does in safari and google chrome)

[image]

this is what it looks like in firefox

[image]

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13722201/Dorset%20Designs/index.html

Comment: Post your html and css code and create a jsfiddle.net .//

Comment: I told you before change your website code. there is lot to change & improve. And its working fine with FF 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey now define in your css `#nav ul` **margin**

As like this

```
    #nav ul {
        margin: 0;
margin-left:5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your `#nav ul` style to include `margin: 0;` before margin-left.

Browsers' default user agent stylesheets will add margins and padding, so make sure you use a CSS reset (like [Eric Meyer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)) to avoid these problems in future.